# Difficulties installing Cro: "Failed to find dependencies: CBOR::Simple"

Tags: raku, cro

I'm hoping to try out the Cro library in Raku: https://cro.services/docs

However, when I try to install it using `zef`, I get this output:

```
zef install Cro::HTTP                                                                                                                                      1 ⨯
===> Searching for: Cro::HTTP
===> Searching for missing dependencies: IO::Socket::Async::SSL, OO::Monitors, IO::Path::ChildSecure, Base64, HTTP::HPACK, Cro::Core:ver<0.8.6>, Cro::TLS:ver<0.8.6>, JSON::Fast, Crypt::Random, JSON::JWT, DateTime::Parse, Log::Timeline
===> Searching for missing dependencies: MIME::Base64, OpenSSL, Digest::HMAC, if, CBOR::Simple
===> Failed to find dependencies: CBOR::Simple
Failed to resolve some missing dependencies
```

Same results on Ubuntu (WSL2) and Kali linux.

Comment: Well, [it seems to exist](https://modules.raku.org/dist/CBOR::Simple:zef:zef:japhb), although it's got a weird denomination. Maybe it's temporary? Do try zef update to see if it's missing in the repos

Comment: The module has been around for at least 6 months and had a major update in September. I just tried installing it myself and that seemed to run OK. Do you know what version of zef you are running @jsaigle? (I installed it with 0.11.11, currently I'm upgrading to 0.13.1. 

It's available in the fez repositories only. I think you may have an older version of zef that doesn't know they exist. Try `zef upgrade zef`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[I asked around on GitHub and IRC](https://logs.liz.nl/cro/2021-11-04.html). The solution was to download and use rakudo-pkg to get a newer version of `zef`. The one that can be installed via `apt` is too old.